# include groupby column values in result

Tags: python, pandas

I use groupby by "department" and then apply a function to the column "flight_length"
The desired result look something like this

| department | co2_footprint |
| --- | --- |
| Account Managment | 10974 |
| Customer Service | 562 |
| HHRR | 2321 |

However, only the co2_footprint column was returned (the value column). I want to include the department column as well. How do I do that?

Here is the code that I used:

```
def co2_footprint(value):
    return value * 0.1

print(df.groupby('department')['flight_length'].apply(co2_footprint))
```

what the data look like:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with the input data as text and the expected output

Comment: Update your post with the output of `print(df.head(10).to_string())` before `groupby`, please.

Comment: Make post reproducible, and I'll remove downvote.

Comment: added the print df.head() as suggested. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not correct, missing an aggregate function like `sum`, `mean` or whatever aggregation custom function:

Try:

```
def co2_footprint(value):
    return sum(value * 0.1)
```

```
>>> df.groupby('department')['flight_length'].apply(co2_footprint).reset_index()

  department  flight_length
0  Marketing     159.914594
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `df.groupby('department')['flight_length'].apply(co2_footprint).reset_index()`

If it does not work, better way is to use `pd.pivot_table()` function. Read more here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: I have tried this. it only add another index column with values 0 and 1

Comment: Please check the revised answer.